# Filter photos by color carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

is their any gem to filter photos by color using carrierwave?

I want users to select a color in a color palette, and depending on the selections, photos with that colors will show.

If not, any guideline? Im totally new to this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [carrierwave-color](https://github.com/sunny/carrierwave-color) gem.
Is stores dominant color in column. So you could filter by this column.

Comment: The carrierwave-color gem now also lets you store the color from a palette so that dominant colors are restricted to the palette you give.